# Is it possible to have single wi-fi device switch between client and hotspot modes?

Tags: wireless, wireless-access-point, hot-spot

I have a portable ubuntu machine (ODROID) with wifi adapter. I can setup wifi hotspot with it, or I can use it to access other wifi network.
The question is can I use it as hotspot, but then switch to client mode when certain network is within the range?

Example. Device is within the range of my home network, so it connects to home network. Then I pick up device and walk away and connection with home network drops, so device is now used as hotspot.

I have a theory/idea about how to make device into hotspot when connection with certain network is lost, but not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

A similar script is discussed here -> [GIYF (Google is Your Friend)](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1488953)